# IBM Urbancode Deploy get current component versions

Tags: api, urbancode

I'm trying to get the current version of a component in a particular environment in U-deploy.  The problem is that the only way I've figured how to get it, is to get the current snapshot, then list versions for that particular snapshot.  But not all of the environments have snapshots.  Is there a way to do this without using the snapshot resource?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a command for that in the public, supported API. If you really need the info, you can try the internal, subject-to-change API. It would be something like this:

```
curl -k -u userName:passw0rd "https://myserver.example.com:8443/rest/deploy/environment/{environmentID}/versions/{componentID}" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

That command returns something like this. In this example, I've got two versions of a component in the environment inventory. The "name" field is the version name.

```
[
  {
   "id": "063c41b5-d330-4b1b-a436-d771e29d39bd",
   "name": "1.1",
   "description": "",
   "type": "INCREMENTAL",
   "created": 1432846976920,
   "active": true,
   "archived": false,
   "sizeOnDisk": 811008
  },
  {
   "id": "92837511-fe7f-4512-9c28-081d0886aee9",
   "name": "1.0",
   "description": "",
   "type": "FULL",
   "created": 1432846976691,
   "active": true,
   "archived": false,
   "sizeOnDisk": 823296
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run the deployment process, you can check the application process property called **currentVersion.name.**
You can get also **previousVersion.name** for the earlier version or **version.name** to the version you are going to install.

Comment: What's exactly this previousVersion.name? I see if I deploy the same version multiple times (uncheck the Only Changed Versions checkbox), then this previousVersion.name is the same as the currentVersion.name. So it's the previous successful deployed version? It doesn't know if it's the same version.